# performing vector intersection in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, vector

I have a vector of vector of unsigned. I need to find the intersection of all these vector of unsigned's for doing so I wrote the following code:

```
int func()
{
   vector<vector<unsigned> > t;
   vector<unsigned> intersectedValues;
   bool firstIntersection=true;
   for(int i=0;i<(t).size();i++)
   {
       if(firstIntersection)
       {
           intersectedValues=t[0];
           firstIntersection=false;
       }else{
           vector<unsigned> tempIntersectedSubjects;                                                              
           set_intersection(t[i].begin(),
                  t[i].end(), intersectedValues.begin(),
                  intersectedValues.end(),
                  std::inserter(tempIntersectedSubjects, tempIntersectedSubjects.begin()));
           intersectedValues=tempIntersectedSubjects;
       }         
       if(intersectedValues.size()==0)
           break;
   }               
}
```

Each individual vector has 9000 elements and there are many such vectors in "t". When I profiled my code I found that set_intersection takes the maximum amount of time and hence makes the code slow when there are many invocations of func(). Can someone please suggest as to how can I make the code more efficient.

I am using: gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

EDIT: Individual vectors in vector "t" are sorted.

Comment: Are your vectors sorted? Also you could try inserting the found elements at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: @Galik Yes the vectors are sorted.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the size of the intersection? If the intersection is expected to "small", that might change the algorithm.

Comment: @StegVerner You listed the compiler, but you didn't post the compiler options used.  If you're profiling unoptimized code, then your results are meaningless until you build an optimized version of the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Compiler options that I am using is O3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a framework to profile the operations but I'd certainly change the code to reuse the readily allocated vector. In addition, I'd hoist the initial intersection out of the loop. Also, `std::back_inserter()` should make sure that elements are added in the correct location rather than in the beginning:

```
int func()
{
    vector<vector<unsigned> > t = some_initialization();
    if (t.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    vector<unsigned> intersectedValues(t[0]);
    vector<unsigned> tempIntersectedSubjects;
    for (std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>>::size_type i(1u);
         i < t.size() && !intersectedValues.empty(); ++i) {
        std::set_intersection(t[i].begin(), t[i].end(),
                              intersectedValues.begin(), intersectedValues.end(),
                             std::back_inserter(tempIntersectedSubjects);
        std::swap(intersectedValues, tempIntersectedSubjects);
        tempIntersectedSubjects.clear();
    }
}
```

I think this code has a fair chance to be faster. It may also be reasonable to intersect the sets different: instead of keeping one set and intersecting with that you could create a new intersection for pairs of adjacent sets and then intersect the first sets with their respect adjacent ones:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> intersections(
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> const& t) {
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> r;
    std::vector<std::vector<unsignned>>::size_type i(0);
    for (; i + 1 < t.size(); i += 2) {
        r.push_back(intersect(t[i], t[i + 1]));
    }
    if (i < t.size()) {
        r.push_back(t[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

std::vector<unsigned> func(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> const& t) {
    if (t.empty()) { /* deal with t being empty... */ }
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> r(intersections(t))
    return r.size() == 1? r[0]: func(r);
}
```

Of course, you wouldn't really implement it like this: you'd use Stepanov's *binary counter* to keep the intermediate sets. This approach assumes that the result is most likely non-empty. If the expectation is that the result will be empty that may not be an improvement.

Comment: reinitialization seems to be neede for variable intersectedValues inside for loop as per OP

Answer (score 2):

You can make `std::set_intersection` as well as a bunch of other standard library algorithms run in parallel by defining `_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` during compilation. That probably has the best work-gain ratio. For documentation see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html).

Obligatory pitfall warning:

> Note that the `_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` define may change the sizes and behavior of standard class templates such as `std::search`, and therefore one can only link code compiled with parallel mode and code compiled without parallel mode if no instantiation of a container is passed between the two translation units. Parallel mode functionality has distinct linkage, and cannot be confused with normal mode symbols.

from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_using.html#parallel_mode.using.parallel_mode).

Another simple, though probably insignificantly small, optimization would be [reserving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) enough space before filling your vectors.

Also, try to find out whether inserting the values at the back instead of the front and then reversing the vector helps. (Although I even think that your code is wrong right now and your `intersectedValues` is sorted the wrong way. If I'm not mistaken, you should use `std::back_inserter` instead of `std::inserter(...,begin)` and then *not* reverse.) While shifting stuff through memory is pretty fast, not shifting should be even faster.

Comment: Where do I define _GLIBCXX_PARALLEL .  I am new to this, can you please help me with this a bit

Comment: @StegVerner Compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL`.

Comment: I am using netbeans, how can I instruct netbeans to use this option

Comment: @StegVerner I don't know, I never used it. Read the documentation or google it, if it is a decent IDE, there should be something like "build options" where you can add defines.

Comment: +1 for reserving vector memory. You know `tempIntersectedSubjects` will be equal or less than `intersectedValues`

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this but maybe something like this would be faster?

```
int func()
{
   vector<vector<unsigned> > t;
   vector<unsigned> intersectedValues;

   // remove if() branching from loop

   if(t.empty())
       return -1;

   intersectedValues = t[0];

   // now start from 1
   for(size_t i = 1; i < t.size(); ++i)
   {
       vector<unsigned> tempIntersectedSubjects;
       tempIntersectedSubjects.reserve(intersectedValues.size()); // pre-allocate

       // insert at end() not begin()
       set_intersection(t[i].begin(),
              t[i].end(), intersectedValues.begin(),
              intersectedValues.end(),
              std::inserter(tempIntersectedSubjects, tempIntersectedSubjects.end()));

       // as these are not used again you can move them rather than copy
       intersectedValues = std::move(tempIntersectedSubjects);

       if(intersectedValues.empty())
           break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Another possibility:**

Thinking about it using `swap()` could optimize the exchange of data and remove the need to re-allocate. Also then the temp constructor can be moved out of the loop.

```
int func()
{
   vector<vector<unsigned> > t;
   vector<unsigned> intersectedValues;

   // remove if() branching from loop

   if(t.empty())
       return -1;

   intersectedValues = t[0];

   // no need to construct this every loop
   vector<unsigned> tempIntersectedSubjects;

   // now start from 1
   for(size_t i = 1; i < t.size(); ++i)
   {
       // should already be the correct size from previous loop
       // but just in case this should be cheep
       // (profile removing this line)
       tempIntersectedSubjects.reserve(intersectedValues.size());

       // insert at end() not begin()
       set_intersection(t[i].begin(),
              t[i].end(), intersectedValues.begin(),
              intersectedValues.end(),
              std::inserter(tempIntersectedSubjects, tempIntersectedSubjects.end()));

       // swap should leave tempIntersectedSubjects preallocated to the
       // correct size
       intersectedValues.swap(tempIntersectedSubjects);
       tempIntersectedSubjects.clear(); // will not deallocate

       if(intersectedValues.empty())
           break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not std::vector call move assignment operator as default? do we need to call std::move()?

Comment: @Steephen No because `tempIntersectedSubjects` is an lvalue (its a named variable). A move will only be automatic for unnamed temporaries that the compiler knows will never be used again.

Comment: @Steephen I had a new thought - using `swap()` may be even more effective (added to answer)

Comment: simple for loop with emplce_back () do better than swap, I observed it in my code!!

Comment: @Steephen really? I thought `swap()` was `O(1)` - simple exchange of data pointers?

Answer (score 1):

To copy elements from  vectors from vector for loop with emplace_back() may save your time. And no need of a flag if you change the iterator index of for loop. So for loop can be optimized, and condition check can be removed for each iteration.

```
void func()
{
   vector<vector<unsigned > > t;
   vector<unsigned int > intersectedValues;

   for(unsigned int i=1;i<(t).size();i++)
   {
        intersectedValues=t[0];

        vector<unsigned > tempIntersectedSubjects;                                                              
        set_intersection(t[i].begin(),
                  t[i].end(), intersectedValues.begin(),
                  intersectedValues.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(tempIntersectedSubjects);
        for(auto &ele: tempIntersectedSubjects)
                intersectedValues.emplace_back(ele);

        if( intersectedValues.empty())
          break;
   }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set::set_intersection can be rather slow for large vectors. It's possible use create a similar function that uses lower_bound. Something like this:

```
template<typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2, typename Function>
void lower_bound_intersection(Iterator1 begin_1, Iterator1 end_1, Iterator2 begin_2, Iterator2 end_2, Function func)
{
    for (; begin_1 != end_1 && begin_2 != end_2;)
    {
        if (*begin_1 < *begin_2)
        {
            begin_1 = begin_1.lower_bound(*begin_2);
            //++begin_1;
        }
        else if (*begin_2 < *begin_1)
        {
            begin_2 = begin_2.lower_bound(*begin_1);
            //++begin_2;
        }
        else // equivalent
        {
            func(*begin_1);
            ++begin_1;
            ++begin_2;
        }
    }
}
```