# intersecting vectors in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a `vector<vector<int> > A;`  of size 44,000. Now I need to intersect 'A' with another vector: `vector<int> B` of size 400,000. The size of inner vectors of A i.e. vector is variable and is of maximum size of 9,000 elements for doing the same I am using the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<44000;i++)
  vector<int> intersect;
  set_intersection(A[i].begin(),A[i].end(),B.begin(),B.end(),
                std::back_inserter(intersect));
```

Is there some way by which I may make the code efficient. All the elements in vector A are sorted i.e. they are of the form `((0,1,4,5),(7,94,830,1000)), etc`. That is, `all elements of A[i]'s vector < all elements of A[j]'s vector if i<j.`

EDIT: One of the solutions which I thought about is to merge all the A[i]'s together into another vector mergedB using:

```
  vector<int> mergedB;
  for(int i=0;i<44000;i++)
       mergedB.insert(mergedB.begin(),mergedB.end(),A[i])
  vector<int> intersect;
  set_intersection(mergedB.begin(),mergedB.end(),B.begin(),B.end(),
                std::back_inserter(intersect));
```

However, I am not getting the reason as to why am I getting almost same performance with both the codes. Can someone please help me understand this

Comment: possible duplicate of [performing vector intersection in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141025/performing-vector-intersection-in-c)

Comment: @BaummitAugen The solution to that was the use of back_inserter...but my question is different here..my vector A is sorted...and I am looking for a more efficient way for intersecting it...

Comment: @StegVerner I believe that you can make the operation linear rather than quadratic by constructing two `unordered_map`s from the vectors.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Can you please explain with the help of an example

Comment: What is the result of intersection? The vector<int> present in both A and B?

Comment: @marom Yes you are correct

Comment: I assume `B` is sorted.  Your `mergedB` looks to me like it will segfault, can you fix your bugs.

Comment: Depending on how much effort you are willing to put into this, the fastest implementation would probably rely on the SIMD instruction set where available. See for instance [Fast Sorted-Set Intersection using SIMD Instructions](http://adms-conf.org/p1-SCHLEGEL.pdf) and [Fast Intersection of Sorted Lists Using SSE Instructions](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/fast-intersection-sorted-lists-sse/). Also, as memory locality can be important it might be worth keeping A as a linear vector to start with if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, `set_itersection` is easy to write.

A fancy way would be to create a concatenating iterator, and go over each element of the lhs vector.  But it is easier to write `set_intersection` manually.

```
template<class MetaIt, class FilterIt, class Sink>
void meta_intersect(MetaIt mb, MetaIt me, FilterIt b, FilterIt e, Sink sink) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  if (b==e) return;
  while (mb != me) {
    auto b2 = begin(*mb);
    auto e2 = end(*mb);
    if (b2==e2) {
      ++mb;
      continue;
    }
    do {
      if (*b2 < *b) {
        ++b2;
        continue;
      }
      if (*b < *b2) {
        ++b;
        if (b==e) return;
        continue;
      }
      *sink = *b2;
      ++sink; ++b; ++b2;
      if (b==e) return;
    } while (b2 != e2);
    ++mb;
  }
}
```

this does not copy elements, other than into the output vector.  It assumes `MetaIt` is an iterator to containers, `FilterIt` is an iterator to a compatible container, and `Sink` is an output iterator.

I attempted to remove all redundant comparisons while keeping the code somewhat readable.  There is one redundant check -- we check `b!=e` and then `b==e` in the single case where we run out of rhs contents.  As this should only happen once, the cost to clarity isn't worth it.

You could possibly make the above more efficient with vectorization on modern hardware.  I'm not an expert at that.  Mixing vectorization with the meta-iteration is tricky.

Comment: @ComeRaczy thanks, I did miss a `++mb`.  But I your edit has some redundant checks which I was trying to avoid.  You'd check `b!=e` or `b==e` an extra number of times equal to the number of `MetaIt` containers I believe.  I agree yours was cleaner, as demonstrated by the fact I had a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Since your vectors are sorted, the simplest and fastest algorithm will be to

1. Set the current element of both vectors to the first value
2. Compare the both current elements. If equal you have an interection, so increment both vectors'
3. If not equal increment the vector with the smallest current element.
4. Goto 2.